# Преобразовать string в Color

Tags: c#, color

Имеется

```cs
string color = ColorPicker.Color.ToString();
```

(использую `Cyotek.Windows.Forms.ColorPicker`)
впоследствии он сохраняется в txt-файл. В txt-файле имеем строку: `Color [A=255, R=255, G=0, B=203]`. При запуске программы я считываю эту строку.

Вопрос:

1. Как преобразовать `string` в `Color`?
2. Как сделать проверку во время преобразования на: `Color [Empty]`?

Дополнение:

1. Ссылка на библиотеку: https://github.com/cyotek/Cyotek.Windows.Forms.ColorPicker

Comment: добавь в вопрос ссылку на саму библиотеку

Comment: Так как судя по всему возвращается стандартный [Color](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color?view=net-5.0) для сохранения просто нужно использовать не `ToString` а тот же [`.ToArgb`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.toargb?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Color_ToArgb), который позволяет получить значение в виде `int32`, далее просто загружать и сохранять обычные целые числа. Перевод в цвет обратно можно осуществить с помощью [`.FromArgb`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Попробовал ваш способ, но на выходе получаю лишь странные значения, например: -63242 или -31464. При считывании этих значений устанавливается чёрный цвет.

Comment: нужно смотреть, как считываешь и устанавливаешь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так можно распарсить

```cs
public Color StringToColor(string text)
{
    Color color = new Color();
    if (!text.Contains("Empty"))
    {
        byte[] channels = text.Split(new [] { ' ', '[', ']', ',' }, StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1).Select(x => byte.Parse(x.Split('=')[1])).ToArray();
        color.A = channels[0];
        color.R = channels[1];
        color.G = channels[2];
        color.B = channels[3];
    }
    return color;
}
```

```cs
ColorPicker.Color = StringToColor("Color [A=255, R=255, G=0, B=203]");
```